# Strange, one expression generates exception but another one not

Tags: php

I've faced some difficulty...

```
function generateExceptionOrError() {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Code below will display `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'`:

`<? generateExceptionOrError();?>`

Code below will also display `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'`:

`<?=generateExceptionOrError();?>`

But another code below will be silent and **wouldn't output any information** about unhandled Excetions. It would display absolute nothing, blank page... Of course, I suppose that Exception is generated, but why it is not displayed!?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=generateExceptionOrError();?>" type="text/css">`

Why? What am I missing?

Thank you

UPDATED: There is not difference exception is generated in method or another kind of errors. The same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've notice in testing is that if an exception occurs inside the `"`'s of an elements attribute, the entire element is not displayed as well as any output afterwards. It seems it might be a browsers/html quirk. Try running your script on the command line and see what output you get.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php generateExceptionOrError() ?>" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<head>
```

Running this on the command line outputs:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'aaa' in /var/www/projects/test.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/projects/test.php(11): generateExceptionOrError()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/projects/test.php on line 4
```

Notice the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="` which is what you would have expected.

This could be at the root of your issue.

Answer (score -2):

the error is there you just cant see it. use firebug or view the source and you will see something like this in your header

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the source is absolutely blank. You can try it by yourself.

Comment: then something else is wrong. try echo '123'; exit; just before the <link ...>